# Spring Boot app in Docker container: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/login.html]

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot Web App that runs correctly when I launch it from Spring Tool Suite or by `java -jar app.jar`

Unfortunately when I make a Docker container of it I get an error due to thymeleaf pages:

> Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/login.html]

I would like to specify that I know that it's not a standard (recommended) location for template pages (`src/main/resources` is meant to be used) but I already added the `src/main/webapp` folder as resource.

```
<resources>          
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
    </resource>             
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

I can't understand why it works when I do `java -jar app.jar` but doesn't work when the same command is executed into a Docker container.

I inspected the container with Visual studio Code and unpacked the `app.jar` and the content is correct, under the `BOOT-INF/classes` I have:

```
WEB-INF
application.properties
templates
logback-spring.xml
...
```

under `WEB-INF` there is the view folder and under the view folder there are my static files: `login.html`, `500.html` etc.

Comment: Why are you placing those in `WEB-INF` at all if it isn't a war that you are deploying? just place them in the default `src/main/resources/templates`. Or do you need a war (then why build a jar instead of a war?).

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right but it's due to a Non Spring Boot project conversion and at the moment is a problem for me to make this change

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Solution posted by the OP ([HK15](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5630632/hk15)) as an edit to the question:</sup>

---

> I had to add the prefix "classpath" in the template resolver Bean:
>
> ```
>  resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/WEB-INF/views/");
> ```
>
> But honestly I don't know why this is necessary only to make it work
> in a Docker container.